# Why is my Partial View is not Showing anything in ASP.NET MVC4 with EDMX model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, edmx

Im having trouble showing the results from a DataBase in my partial view, while i am getting no errors as a result of a previous question  posted the information does not display.  I have tried to use viewbags to see if other elements of the page display to no success.  However the search bar feature i implemented does show which makes it all the more confusing.

The model properties are taken from an edmx model from another project accessed through the database both projects are connected to.

It is my aim to have the partial view show the information of the database on the home index page and to include a search function (which i believe is working but i wont know until i have the partial view displaying. Seeing as i am not getting errors returned my previous question was essentially answered and for anyone going through the same problem would benefit from two solutions to this issue.

I have narrowed it down to possible options, due to my ability it's up for debate.  The edmx model is not being called/referenced by the PatientProfile and PatientListViewModel.

im not sure if multiple tables F2FDataEntities (the .edmx model) can be used in the same view so i created a listmodel (PatientProfile) and a view model (PatientlistViewModel)

**HomeController.cs**

```
using FaceToFaceWebsite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PagedList;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public F2FDataEntities _db = new F2FDataEntities();

        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null, int page = 1)
        {
            var viewModel = new PatientListViewModel();

            viewModel.PatientProfile = new List<PatientProfile>();

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_Patient", viewModel);
            }

            return View(viewModel);

        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Patients()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Help()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Contact Us";

            return View();
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_db != null)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

}
```

**PatientListViewModel.cs**  (Model)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    public class PatientListViewModel
    {
     public List<PatientProfile> PatientProfile { get; set; }
    }

    public class Patient
    {
        public IEnumerable<User> UserID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<User> CodeName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Device> Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Session> ReachedFinish { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PatientProfile.cs**  (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{

    public class PatientProfile : DbContext
    {
       public PatientProfile() : base("F2FDataEntities")
        {

        }
       public IEnumerable<User> UserID { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<User> CodeName { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Device> Name { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Session> ReachedFinish { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@model FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

@using(Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions{
    HttpMethod="get",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId="patientList"}))

{
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
}
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Patient.cshtml", Model.PatientProfile)

<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")" data-f2fw-ajax="true" data-f2fw-target="#patientList">
    <input type="text" name="searchTerm" data-f2fw-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete")" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
</form>
```

**Views/Shared/_Patient.cshtml** (Partial View)

```
@model List<PatientProfile>


@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>UserID: @item.CodeName</h4>
            <span>Finished: @item.ReachedFinish</span>
            <p>Machine: @item.Name</p>
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
```

Thankyou for taking the time to read this, im still relatively new to MVC and entity so i do apologise if the mistake is stupid.

**-Update-**

I have added the line

```
viewModel.PatientProfile = _db.PatientProfiles;
```

to the home controller, and generated a property stub in

**F2FData.Context.cs (inside of F2FData.edmx, then inside of  F2FData.Context.tt)**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class F2FDataEntities : DbContext
    {
        public F2FDataEntities()
            : base("name=F2FDataEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<C__MigrationHistory> C__MigrationHistory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Exercis> Exercises { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PoseChannel> PoseChannels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pos> Poses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ScreenInteractionsEntry> ScreenInteractionsEntries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SessionExercis> SessionExercises { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public System.Collections.Generic.List<PatientProfile> PatientProfiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However the view is still not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading anything from the database. You create an new instance of the view model, and only assign empty lists, which means the view model is empty, and there's nothing to show in the views. You wouldn't get an error in that case.

It should be something like.

```
var viewModel = new PatientListViewModel();
viewModel.PatientProfile = _db.PatientProfiles;
return View(viewModel);
```

Notice how we retrieve the patients and profiles from the database?

Comment: Thankyou, i have added an update to my question to give you an idea of what is happening.  I missed this out orignally as i did not know it existed.  F2FData.Context.CS contains the DbSets for the edmx model i am using.

Comment: @Nilmag PatientProfiles shouldn't be a `List<PatientProfile>` in your DbContext. It should be a `DbSet<PatientProfile>`. And `PatientProfile` shouldn't inherit from `DbSet`. You should only have one DbContext, with a `DbSet` for each set of data in the database.

Comment: I am now getting an error at: viewModel.PatientProfile = _db.PatientProfiles;   of  "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientProfile>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientProfile>' "

Comment: @Nilmag Change your view model to accept an `IEnumerable<PatientProfile>` instead of a `List<PatientProfile>`. Same thing for your views.

Comment: Thankyou that fixed the error, however i am still getting nothing from my partial view besides the search feature. Sorry.

Comment: @Nilmag Set a breakpoint in your controller, and inspect `viewModel.PatientProfile = _db.PatientProfiles;` and see how many patient profiles it retrieves from the DB. This will help you locate your problem. You may need to change it to `viewModel.PatientProfile = _db.PatientProfiles.ToList();` to get meaningful information in the debugger due to the delayed execution of EF.

Comment: Where can i "inspect" to see how many patient profiles it retrieves from the db?

Comment: @Nilmag You can set a breakpoint in your controller, then step through until your view model is populated, then hover your mouse over the view model and dig through the properties. Or you could write to `System.Diagnostics.Debug` with the debugger attached and inspect the output window. If you don't know how to set breakpoints and step through code in Visual Studio, you should look it up, and that's one of the most critical skills you can have.

Comment: Thankyou, i will get right on it.  I will mark this as answered as you have fixed alot of the problems.

Comment: From what i've gathered it's telling me that the viewModel is null. Does that mean ive referenced the models in the edmx incorrectly in my PatientProfile and PatientListViewModel?

Comment: @Nilmag Your view model can't be null, because of `var viewModel = new PatientListViewModel();`. Step through until that line is executed, then step a little past it where you retrieve the patient profiles and put them in the view model, then look at the number of patient profiles.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you are giving the list any values to loop through.

I see here that you create a new viewmodel entity, and a new list, but unless I am missing something the list is never **populated**

```
        var viewModel = new PatientListViewModel();

        viewModel.PatientProfile = new List<PatientProfile>();
```

After this line make sure to give the list some actual information to loop through in your partial view, or nothing will display.

I typical addition would be something along the lines of:

```
viewmodel.PatientProfile = _db.Example......(get a list, or values from database)
```

Comment: Thankyou, i have done as you and mason have stated however the same problem persists.  I have added an update to my question to give you an idea.

Comment: No matter what code you have, if you don't supply any data to the list, then your foreach() loop will not have anything to loop through, therefore having no data. You must populate the list before sending it to the partial view.